# Does Google App Engine Projection Queries are supported by Web2py?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, web2py

I'm making a good progress using Web2py and Google App Engine, but now I have to decide how to store images without waste GAE resources!

I have a "table" were I store products. 
Each product can have a maximum of 12 picutes.

When I request the product page, lets say:
/product/7484/

I need only the product informations, without the pictures, but GAE engine get all fields from datastore! I thought that using Google [App Engine Projection Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection), this could be solved and I would only fetch the fields I need!

Is that possible with Web2py or will I have to change my database to store imagens on another "table"?

I only will need fetch each picute field when they get requested by browser... but now, each picture requested cause the whole product entity being fetched from database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have it as an experimental feature in trunk. Perhaps you can help us test it. Nothing special to do just the usual:

```
db(query).select(db.table.field1, db.table.field2, etc.)
```

unless the query selects a single record by id, the arguments of select are converted into a projection query. Unfortunately GAE does not support projection for get_by_id().

Thanks to Christian (howesc) who pulled this off within 24 hrs from you requesting the feature. Please join us on the web2py google group if you can help testing.

Comment: I put some tests [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/web2py/ZcCngD6yEag). Thanks Massimo and howesc!